# JQuery toggle unknown number of tables

Tags: jquery, toggle, show-hide

I have a page that queries events on a selected calendar date and groups them in an individual table for each different event type.

Obviously this list could get quite large and rather than having everything displayed and the user having to scroll a lot I was hoping I could use the toggle function to hide a list of events for an event type when they click the table header for that event type.

The issue I'm struggling to get my head around is that I have no idea how many different event types there will be for any selected date so how do I write a function that will hide only that selected event type?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Anything might help: Code (preferably), use cases, etc. See: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not really giving us much in your question to go on so perhaps I'm totally off with this answer.

But I think you need to add an `event-type` attribute to the elements that represent the events, then you can use jQuery select the elements and apply a toggle.

```
<style>
display-none { display:none; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$().ready(function () {

    $('div[event-type]').toggle('display-none');

    $('div[event-type-header]').bind('click', function () {
        var eventType = $(this).attr('event-type-header');
        $('div[event-type="' + eventType + '"]').toggle('hide-event-type');
    });
});
</script>

<!-- header -->
<div event-type-header="party">toggle party</div>
<div event-type-header="auction">toggle auction</div>

<!-- content -->
<div event-type="party">party1</div>
<div event-type="auction">auction1</div>
<div event-type="party">party2</div>
<div event-type="auction">auction2</div>
```

Comment: Okay so what I do is I query the distinct event types for the selected date and loop this around a table so that there's a separate table for each event type. Within the loop I then loop a query that gets the events for that event type for that selected date.

Does that help any?

Comment: Well is the example I've put even close? jsFiddle seems to be done at the moment so sorry for the full script.

Comment: I'm using tables which probably makes it less straightforward! http://jsfiddle.net/gXyhB/

Comment: coldfusion? that jsfiddle doesn't really help

Comment: Anyways I think you should be able to apply to method in my answer to what ever style of html you've outputted.

Comment: Yeah it's ColdFusion. Yeah I was able to apply it, thanks very much for your help.